# Why background-image doesn't change on mobile device?

Tags: html, css

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url("./Images/mainPage.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    html {    
        background-image: url("./Images/smalMainPage.png");
    }
}
```

Part without "@media only..." works on devices with screen size lower than 750px. Why this is happening?

Comment: it should work properly. Do you have correct path to your small image or does this image exist? Any errors in browser's console?

Comment: path is correct, because when I manually change image name in browser it swaps for smaller. Console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: I have no ideas. Please check an answer below. This guy provided a working codepen with similar code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

tag may be missing? Because working on codepen: https://codepen.io/dgknca/pen/REwKrV